# взаимодействие независимых компонентов ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook, state

Есть два независимых функциональных ( не имеют общего предка и один не является родителем второго) компонента React на хуках. Нужно сделать чтобы изменение состояния в первом компоненте приводило к изменениям состояния во втором .
подскажите как это реализовать проще всего - копать в сторону Redux или можно обойтись хуками? (сделать один родителем второго или дать им общего родителя -не предлагать)

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос _копать в сторону Redux или можно обойтись хуками_

Comment: так какой вариант ?

Comment: Любой, и тот и тот вариант по своему хороши, если вы до этого использовали хуки и контекст, то продолжайте хуками, тут все зависит от желания/стиля написания.